# How to bind behaviour in new elements in a vuejs repeat block?

Tags: jquery, vue.js

I have a v-repeat block with the following HTML

```
<div v-repeat="tour:tours.data">
             <div class="flipblock">
                 <div class="front">FRONT</div>
                 <div class="back">BACK</div>
             </div>
        </div>
```

and trying to bind the flip behaviour of the [flip jquery plugin](http://nnattawat.github.io/flip/).

My vue script is something like this.

```
new Vue({
el: '#tab-content',

ready: function(){
    this.fetchOneDayTours();
    $(".flipblock").flip();
},

methods:{
    fetchOneDayTours:function(){
        this.$http.get('http://XXXX',null,
            function(tours){
                this.$set('onedaytours',tours);
            }
            , {
                headers: {
                    'X-Authorization':'76361d78ff3712ecf95f0989580a063e6ef3c211'
                }
            }
        )

    }
```

Problem is that I the flip() behaviour is not working inside in the v-repeat block, most probably because those elements are dynamically created. How can I bind this behaviour to all future elements with the class of .flipblock ?

p.s.: The flip() behaviour works just fine outside vue.js repeat block.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a watch:

```
data: {
    "onedaytours": null
},
ready: function(){
    this.$watch("onedaytours", function (newValue, oldValue) {
        this.$nextTick(function () {
            $(".flipblock").flip();
        });
    });

    this.fetchOneDayTours();
},
```

This assumes that .flip() is safe to call on elements multiple times. Otherwise, you'll either need to do something like mark the elements that have been initialized so you can skip them, remove flip from all elements and then apply to all again, etc.

The `$nextTick` call is needed to allow the DOM to update (when Vue is using async batch updates).